# Is it possible to Animate a Binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, binding

Is it possible to Animate a picture which i get through binding? As i am new to C# and WPF i am trying to use the Features like binding. I want the old picture fading out (Opacity probaply, but is this an option with Binding?) and the new one fading in. Or is it better to handle everything in the code behind, where i get the image from the folder and binding it afterwards.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Screensaver.ScreensaverControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Screensaver"
             mc:Ignorable="d" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Image Visibility="Visible" Source="{Binding DisplayedImagePath}" Name="Bild" Stretch="Uniform" />

    </Grid>
</UserControl>

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Screensaver
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ScreensaverControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ScreensaverControl : UserControl
    {
        private Timer _timer;

        public ScreensaverControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += ScreensaverControl_Loaded;
            this.Unloaded += ScreensaverControl_Unloaded;
        }

        private void ScreensaverControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _timer = new Timer(OnTimer, _timer, 10, Timeout.Infinite);
        }

        private void ScreensaverControl_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _timer.Dispose();
            _timer = null;
        }

        private int _index = -1;
        private void OnTimer(object state)
        {
            try
            {
                var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\mhj\source\repos\Screensaver\Fotos\", "*.png");
                if (files.Length > 0)
                {
                    _index++;
                    if (_index >= files.Length)
                        _index = 0;

                    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => DisplayedImagePath = files[_index]);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                if (_timer != null)
                    _timer.Change(10000, Timeout.Infinite);
            }
        }

        public string DisplayedImagePath
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayedImagePathProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DisplayedImagePathProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DisplayedImagePath.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayedImagePathProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayedImagePath", typeof(string), typeof(ScreensaverControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    }

}
```

Comment: You can of course animate the Opacity of an Image element, but that would be unrelated to the Binding of its Source property. To make an actual blending effect, you would also need to have two Image elements on top of each other, and animate the Opacity of both, one from 1 to 0, the other one from 0 to 1.

Comment: But i only have 1 picture binded, should i just put another one over it. How can i set the opacity, as i need a fade out effect it would be better to do that in the code behind. Sadly i can't get the opacity to work in c#.

Comment: Also consider using a DispatcherTimer instead of System.Threading.Timer. Its Tick handler already runs in the UI thread, so there is no need for Dispatcher.Invoke.

Comment: So should there be a blending effect or not?

Comment: It looks also totally odd that the image property in your view model is of type `string`. It should be `ImageSource`, exactly like the `Source` property of the Image class.

Comment: Maybe this exercise is a step on the route to other things. When the UI is rather richer, an approach I've seen used works with a visualbrush used as the background of a container the foreground elements are in. EG when you're navigating one usercontrol to another.

Comment: Can using the Threading.Timer cause any negative effects? A blending effect would be nice. Does Using String isntead of Image have any negative effects? How can I use a visualbrush on this, i am still very new to c#.

Comment: Negative effects not, only bad design. I'd suggest you start without the DisplayedImagePath property (because it is only used internally) and just set the Image's Source property from the code behind of the UserControl, i.e. from a Tick handler of a DispatcherTimer in that control. Whenever the Tick handler is called, change the Source property and animate the Opacity.

Comment: If i do it without the DisplayedImagePath i can't bind the image anymore, how would this work then? Can i still use my timer method with the DispatcherTimer, or do i need to revamp my whole code?

Comment: You don't need that binding. Just call `Bild.Source = new BitmapSoure(new Uri(...))`.

Comment: If i do that it wont change the picture after 10 seconds or am i missing something?

Comment: In a Tick handler of course!

Comment: The tick handler only improves my design, but how to i get the picture from the timer(Tickhandler) to the Xaml file without binding? If i provide the source the image  would be static and can't be changed.

Comment: By setting `Bild.Source`. You already assigned the name `Bild` in XAML.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you mean, i am sorry i am probably missing the forest through the tress but i am still a very green beginner with wpf and c#.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code of a simple screen saver control. It has a dependency property for the image directory. You should add another dependency property for the change interval, and perhaps also a second Image for a blending effect.

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ScreenSaverControlTest.ScreenSaverControl" ...>
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="image1"/>
        <Image x:Name="image2"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and code behind:

```
public partial class ScreenSaverControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageDirectoryProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(ImageDirectory), typeof(string), typeof(ScreenSaverControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(ImageDirectoryPropertyChanged));

    private readonly DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    private string[] imagePaths = new string[0];
    private int currentImageIndex = -1;

    public ScreenSaverControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        timer.Tick += (s, e) => NextImage();
        timer.Start();
    }

    public string ImageDirectory
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ImageDirectoryProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageDirectoryProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void ImageDirectoryPropertyChanged(
        DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ssc = (ScreenSaverControl)o;
        var directory = (string)e.NewValue;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(directory) && Directory.Exists(directory))
        {
            ssc.imagePaths = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.jpg");
        }
        else
        {
            ssc.imagePaths = new string[0];
        }

        ssc.currentImageIndex = -1;
        ssc.NextImage();
    }

    private void NextImage()
    {
        if (imagePaths.Length > 0)
        {
            if (++currentImageIndex >= imagePaths.Length)
            {
                currentImageIndex = 0;
            }

            SetImage(new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePaths[currentImageIndex])));
        }
    }

    private void SetImage(ImageSource imageSource)
    {
        var fadeOut = new DoubleAnimation(0d, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        var fadeIn = new DoubleAnimation(1d, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        var newImage = image1;
        var oldImage = image2;

        if (image1.Source != null)
        {
            newImage = image2;
            oldImage = image1;
        }

        fadeOut.Completed += (s, e) => oldImage.Source = null;

        oldImage.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, fadeOut);
        newImage.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, fadeIn);
        newImage.Source = imageSource;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
<local:ScreenSaverControl ImageDirectory="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures"/>
```

Comment: I really really thank you for your Post. So there is no way i can just do it my way, as it took me way longer to come up with the code than i care to admit. I understand the most part of your code, the only thing where it gets me is what is s? I know e is the Event, is s also one? Again i really appreciate your help.

Comment: It's the `sender` argument of an EventHandler. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.tick?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Changed the code to use two Image elements with a blending effect.